# Subversion and test deployment

Tags: svn, version-control, deployment, project-management

I have a client who I'm trying to convince to implement Subversion (I know, I know).  My pitch goes something like this: His test domain is visible to Google and other webcrawlers, despite his best efforts (robot.txt not withstanding).  By putting the repository on an svn:// URL, we could avoid having the code crawled until the deployment to the live domain.

My question is: is there a way to deploy to a test domain, then bring it back down after work has been done.  I guess what I'm asking after is some means of switching the test domain on and off easily, and through Subversion or some tool in conjunction with Subversion.

This is more of a client-management issue, but y'all have never let me down.

Comment: ... I'm a bit confused, you obviously can't run the website over the 'svn://' URI ... via the browser, that's only good for browsing the source ...

Comment: I also don't really understand link between the test domain and svn references. Also "...is there a way to deploy to a test domain, then bring it back down after work has been done.", sure bring the site down?? Please revise the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many reasons to use SVN, but I don't think "preventing your code from being crawled" is one of them.

If your development areas and code can be crawled by search engines, you have a serious system administration issue.  There are dozens of solutions to this problem... IP whitelists, HTTP Authentication on a per-site basis, per-domain ACLs, etc.  [HTTP Auth](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) takes 5 seconds to set up... you should really have *something* going.

The myriad of benefits for SVN are covered everywhere, so I won't extoll it's virtues here.  Google "why use SVN" to compile a laundry list of good reasons.

As far as test domains go, that's not really something to be controlling with SVN either.  It's as simple as a quick web server configuration change to determine which sites are live and which aren't.  However, if you had controlled access to your test domain, you wouldn't even need to do this.

Comment: The test server is a) not my server and b) full of legacy code.  I'm inheriting this project, and the client is used to a certain workflow.  I was just wondering if there was there was something I could use to, frankly, sell the client on SVN.  I have to say, the idea of having a web browser that treats svn:// URIs like http:// would be a really cool way to test web apps.

An IP whitelist is going to have to be path, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea of a testbed web app and storing your code in svn are two differnt issues.

To avoid google crawling your testbed, why not run it behind a firewall?  Could you use localhost for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Lock down the url/folder via .htaccess and be done with it. This has *zero* to do with Subversion.